Синонимизировать метки [elastic] и [elasticsearch]
Синонимизировать:
elastic - 5 вопросов, описания нет
elasticsearch - 229 вопроса, описание есть
Основная метка - elasticsearch
Потому что:

Все вопросы для elastic связаны с elasticsearch.
На stackoverflow.com данные метки синонимичны - т.е. там тоже при большем количестве вопросов не нашлось причин для их разделения.


Готово!
updating post history, 5 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 5 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 0 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'elastic': [elastic] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 229
tag remapping of [elasticsearch] and [elastic] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym elastic -> elasticsearch was approved!

